# How to call an index in 'MultiIndex' in 'DataFrameGroupBy'

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

My main dataframe is called df which has 5 columns: lat, lon, date, gfa and wglc with 25M rows.
I created a multi-index DataFrameGroupBy with the following code:

```
df_sort=df.set_index(['lat','lon','date']).sort_index(level['lat','lon','date'])
df_grouped = df_sort.groupby(level=['lat','lon'])
```

and each cell of df_grouped looks like e.g.,:

|  |  |  | gfa | wglc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| lat | lon | date |  |  |
| 51.0 | -172.0 | 2015-01-01 | -1 | 0.0 |
|  |  | 2015-01-02 | -1 | 3.0 |
|  |  | 2015-01-03 | -1 | 1.0 |
|  |  | 2015-01-04 | 5 | 0.0 |
|  |  | 2015-01-05 | -1 | 0.0 |
|  |  | 2015-01-06 | -1 | 0.0 |
|  |  | 2015-01-07 | -1 | 0.0 |

I want to go through column "gfa" and when it is not -1, one new column is created which has the values of wglc column for the same day and 10 days backwards. In other words, if `df_grouped["gfa"] != -1`, store the value of "wglc" column of the same days and 10 days before. I wrote the following for the conditional statement but I do not know how to call index of "date":

```
for cell, cell_info in df_grouped:
   cell_info.loc[cell_info['gfa'] != -1, 'wglc10lag'] = cell_info.iloc[??,'wglc']
```

I would appreciate any hint. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly,what value do you want if the gfa column is -1 ? Based on my understanding, I suggest that instead of looping through the DataFrame you could do this:

```
df_grouped['wglc10lag'] = np.where(df_grouped['gfa'] != -1, df_grouped['date'],'Not -1')
```

In the above code, inplace of 'Not -1' , you should mention what value you want to enter for 'gfa' == -1

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually this is not what I want to do. My main question is how to find "date" index if  `df_grouped['gfa'] != -1` ?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand the question correctly, does my edit work ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. No, not yet. the thing is that df_grouped is grouped. When I use your suggestion, I get "KeyError: 'Column not found: date'". Your solution works when I work with normal dataframe not "grouped". This is my main issue that I don't know how to access to "date" index when it is sorted and grouped!

Comment: I found the solution. It is explained [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/advanced.html#advanced). I should use [pandas.IndexSlice](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.IndexSlice.html#pandas.IndexSlice)

Comment: Amazing ! I couldn’t understand the question, my mistake